# Automapper through relations in Entity Framework

Tags: automapper

As a newbie to automapper (v10.0.0) I'm trying to replace one of my queries.  I currently use this to generate my response:

```cs
var query = from a in _context.ApprovalStatuses.AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.ApprovalOrder).ThenInclude(x => x.Worker)
            where a.RequestId == request.Id
            orderby a.ApprovalOrder.Position
            let w = a.ApprovalOrder.Worker
            select new RequestApprovalStatusDTO {
                AssignedUtc = a.AssignedUtc,
                Comments = a.Comments,
                DecisionDateUtc = a.ApprovedDateUtc ?? a.RejectedDateUtc,
                Email = w.Email,
                Name = w.Name,
                Uuid = a.Uuid
            };
```

So I started by creating my mapping in my `Profile` subclass:

```cs
CreateMap<ApprovalStatus, RequestApprovalStatusDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.DecisionDateUtc, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.ApprovedDateUtc ?? y.RejectedDateUtc))
    .ForMember(x => x.Email, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.ApprovalOrder.Worker.Email))
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.ApprovalOrder.Worker.Name));
```

And then I rewrote the query like so:

```cs
var query = _context.ApprovalStatuses
    .Include(x => x.ApprovalOrder)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Worker)
    .Where(x => x.RequestId == request.Id)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ApprovalOrder.Position);

return Ok(_mapper.Map<RequestApprovalStatusDTO>(query));
```

At runtime, it's telling me

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
> Object -> RequestApprovalStatusDTO
> System.Object -> BoltOn.RequestApprovalStatusDTO
> lambda_method(Closure , object , RequestApprovalStatusDTO , ResolutionContext )

I understand it's telling me that it doesn't know how to convert from `object`, but I'm not sure why it's trying to do that since `query` is an `IOrderedQueryable<ApprovalStatus>`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lucian's pointer I was able to solve it like so:

```cs
var query = _context.ApprovalStatuses
    .Where(x => x.Request.Uuid == uuid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ApprovalOrder.Position);

var approvals = await _mapper.ProjectTo<RequestApprovalStatusDTO>(query).ToArrayAsync();
if (approvals.Length == 0)
    return NotFound();

return Ok(approvals);
```